# Dynamically loaded texture2D and different surface formats

Tags: xna

Does anyone know if it is possible in XNA to **dynamically** load bitmap from jpg files and draw texture2d using other surface formats then `SurfaceFormat.Color`?

Because of memory/speed limits I need to use `Bgr565` or `Dxt surface` formats.
I could use content pipeline and set Content Processor, Texture Format to DxtCompressed but `Content.Load` doesn't allow dynamic texture load.

I could use `Texture2D.FromStream` but it creates `SurfaceFormat.Color` texture only.
I experiment with creating empty Texture2D in desired surface format and try to manualy set bitmap data using `SetData` but it seems like a too complicated way.

Is there `Texture2D.FromStream` and `Texture2D.SetData` the only way to dynamically load jpg files and use them as `Bgr565` or `Dxt` surface format textures?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't got a solution for loading with SurfaceFormat. But you can load them and draw them to a rendertarget with the desired format, then copy the textureData to a new texture you create with the required format?

Will increase loading-times, but should allow the sped-up execution you are looking for?